# JavaFX- Editing tables- Double cannot be cast to String

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'm trying to make an editable table that lets the user input values. The value input works, but when a user makes an edit, it doesn't save and outputs an error message. Here is my code:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(450);
    stage.setHeight(550);

    final Label label = new Label("Data");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    table.setEditable(true);




    TableColumn aCol = new TableColumn("a");
    aCol.setMinWidth(100);
    aCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("A"));

    aCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<info, Double>forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));

    aCol.setOnEditCommit(
        new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<info, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<info, String> t) {
                ((info) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setA(Double.parseDouble(t.getNewValue()));
            }
        }
    );

    TableColumn bCol = new TableColumn("B");
    bCol.setMinWidth(200);
    bCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("b"));

    bCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<info, Double>forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));
    bCol.setOnEditCommit(
        new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<info, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<info, String> t) {
                ((info) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setB(Double.parseDouble(t.getNewValue()));
            }
        }
    );

    table.setItems(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(aCol,bCol);

    final TextField addA = new TextField();
    addA.setPromptText("A");
    addA.setMaxWidth(aCol.getPrefWidth());

    final TextField addB = new TextField();
    addB.setMaxWidth(BCol.getPrefWidth());
    addB.setPromptText("B");



    final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
    addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            data.add(new info(
                   Double.parseDouble( addA.getText()),

                    Double.parseDouble(addB.getText())));
            addA.clear();
            addB.clear();

        }
    });

    hb.getChildren().addAll(addB, addA, addButton);
    hb.setSpacing(3);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

My error message is:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double
cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer me

Comment: Is `TableColumn bCol` supposed to be `TableColumn<info, Double> Col` ? If not, what is the actual data type of that column? Why are you setting the cell factory to something that returns a `TableCell<info, Double>` but using a `CellEditEvent<info, String>` in the `onEditCommit` handler. Don't use raw types: then the compiler will force you to make the types consistent throughout.

Comment: And why are you setting the cell factory on each column twice? The first cell factory will just be replaced by the second one each time.

Comment: Setting aCol and bCol to info doubles worked, thank you! As for the setting cell factory twice, I just forgot to remove the first one. Thanks again.